# Black spots on echeveria leaves - cause?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, diseases, succulents

**Activity on 28-01-2019:**

1. Watered - soil is damp as of 29-01-2019, but it is a fast-draining cactus mix.
2. Pest control - sprayed 2~3 times with pyrethrum bug spray (brand below)
3. Fertilized - about half a teaspoon of general NPK fertilizer granules spread around the edges of the pot (brand below)

**Noticed on 29-01-2019:**

Black spots and marks on my babies :(

Pic 1 of 1 of my black prince:

[image: Echeveria Black Prince black spots]

Pic 1 of 2 of my other:

[image: Echeveria forgot type black marks]

Pic 2 of 2 of my other:

[image: Echeveria forgot type black marks]

**What is happening?**

The last time these plants were watered before 28-01-2019 was just under 2 weeks ago.

The brand of bug spray I used is this: http://www.multicrop.com.au/home-garden-products/pyrethrum-long-life-natural-insect-spray.php

The fertilizer I used is this: http://www.brunnings.com.au/all-purpose-npk-fertiliser-2261.html